# Datetime format value for Datepicker

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs
I have a datepicker on my html and it displays a ('YYYY-mm-dd') format

This is my html code:

input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="form.exceldate" name="date" data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" data-max-date="today" data-autoclose="1" bs-datepicker placeholder="Date"

However,when i receive the value it is pass like this in may js:
Wed Jan 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

Can someone help me how to format this in ('YYYY-mm-dd')?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`angular-date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) Filter

```
{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}<br />
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
 $scope.date = new Date();
   
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="dobController">
  {{date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to change yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-MM-dd